# How to add AlertDialog in my AndroNoise

Tags: android

I have ask a question before about change method OnClick to method lifecycle

But I think the problem was solving.

But in this new question is same with before but different.

Now i have ask how add alertdialog to my source code. I have 3 aletdialog will show when the noise until 70 dB , 80 dB and 100 dB.

Here's MY CODE

```js
package com.andronoise;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements InputListener{

  InputSuara micInput;
  TextView mdBTextView;
  TextView mdBFractionTextView;
  LevelBar mBarLevel;
  double mGain = 2500.0 / Math.pow(10.0, 90.0 / 20.0);
  double mRmsSmoothed;
  double mAlpha = 0.9;
  public double dB;
  private int mSampleRate;
  private int mAudioSource;
  private volatile boolean mDrawing;
  private volatile int mDrawingCollided;

  private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
  
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    micInput = new InputSuara(this);
    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBarLevel = (LevelBar)findViewById(R.id.bar_level_drawable_view);
    mdBTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dBTextView);
    mdBFractionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dBFractionTextView);

    final ToggleButton onOffButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(
        R.id.on_off_toggle_button);

    ToggleButton.OnClickListener tbListener =
        new ToggleButton.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
       
        if (onOffButton.isChecked()) {
          readPreferences();
          micInput.setSampleRate(mSampleRate);
          micInput.setAudioSource(mAudioSource);
          micInput.start();
          
        } else {
          micInput.stop();
        }
     
      }
      
    };
    onOffButton.setOnClickListener(tbListener);     
      }  

  private void readPreferences() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("LevelMeter",
        MODE_PRIVATE);
    mSampleRate = preferences.getInt("SampleRate", 8000);
    mAudioSource = preferences.getInt("AudioSource", 
        MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION);
  }
  
  public void Alert () {
   
   if (dB >= 70 || dB <80) {
          AlertDialog.Builder build = new
            AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                build.setTitle("Alert!!!").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setMessage("Level 70 dB, kebisingan dalam tingkat rendah")
                .setPositiveButton("Close",null).show();
         }
         else if (dB >=80 || dB <100) {
          AlertDialog.Builder build = new
            AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                build.setTitle("Alert!!!").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setMessage("Level 80 dB, kebisingan dalam tingkat sedang Waspada !")
                .setPositiveButton("Close",null).show();
         }
         else if ( dB >= 100) {
          AlertDialog.Builder build = new
            AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                build.setTitle("Alert!!!").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setMessage("Level 100 dB, berbahaya jika lebih dari 1 menit!!! Segera menghindar")
                .setPositiveButton("Close",null).show();
         };
  }

  public void processAudioFrame(short[] audioFrame) {
    if (!mDrawing) {
      mDrawing = true;
      double rms = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < audioFrame.length; i++) {
        rms += audioFrame[i]*audioFrame[i];
      }
      rms = Math.sqrt(rms/audioFrame.length);
      mRmsSmoothed = mRmsSmoothed * mAlpha + (1 - mAlpha) * rms;
      final double rmsdB = 20.0 * Math.log10(mGain * mRmsSmoothed);
      dB = 20 + rmsdB;
      
      mBarLevel.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
        public void run() {
          mBarLevel.setLevel(( 10 + rmsdB) / 90);
          DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##");
          mdBTextView.setText(df.format(dB));
          
          int one_decimal = (int) (Math.round(Math.abs(rmsdB * 10))) % 10;
          mdBFractionTextView.setText(Integer.toString(one_decimal));
          mDrawing = false;
    }
          });
      
    } else {
      mDrawingCollided++;
      Log.v(TAG, "Level bar update collision, i.e. update took longer " +
          "than 20ms. Collision count" + Double.toString(mDrawingCollided));
    }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in yours if conditions

```
     if (dB >= 70 || dB <80){
    //do something
    }              
     else if (dB >=80 || dB <100){
    //do something
    }
```

e.g db=95 the app will go to the first if

the correct code is:

```
    if (dB >= 70 && dB <80){
    //do something
    } else if (dB >=80 && dB <100){
    //do something
    }else{
    //do something
     }
```

so

```
        package com.andronoise;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.ToggleButton;

    import java.text.DecimalFormat;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements InputListener{

      InputSuara micInput;
      TextView mdBTextView;
      TextView mdBFractionTextView;
      LevelBar mBarLevel;
      double mGain = 2500.0 / Math.pow(10.0, 90.0 / 20.0);
      double mRmsSmoothed;
      double mAlpha = 0.9;
      public double dB;
      private int mSampleRate;
      private int mAudioSource;
      private volatile boolean mDrawing;
      private volatile int mDrawingCollided;

      private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        micInput = new InputSuara(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBarLevel = (LevelBar)findViewById(R.id.bar_level_drawable_view);
        mdBTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dBTextView);
        mdBFractionTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dBFractionTextView);

        final ToggleButton onOffButton=(ToggleButton)findViewById(
            R.id.on_off_toggle_button);

        ToggleButton.OnClickListener tbListener =
            new ToggleButton.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

            if (onOffButton.isChecked()) {
              readPreferences();
              micInput.setSampleRate(mSampleRate);
              micInput.setAudioSource(mAudioSource);
              micInput.start();

            } else {
              micInput.stop();
            }

          }

        };
        onOffButton.setOnClickListener(tbListener);     
          }  

      private void readPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("LevelMeter",
            MODE_PRIVATE);
        mSampleRate = preferences.getInt("SampleRate", 8000);
        mAudioSource = preferences.getInt("AudioSource", 
            MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_RECOGNITION);
      }

      public void Alert () {

        if (dB >= 70 && dB <80) {
            AlertDialog.Builder build = new
                    AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            build.setTitle("Alert!!!").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setMessage("Level 70 dB, kebisingan dalam tingkat rendah")
                    .setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }).show();


        }
        else if (dB >=80 && dB <100) {
            AlertDialog.Builder build = new
                    AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            build.setTitle("Alert!!!").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setMessage("Level 80 dB, kebisingan dalam tingkat sedang Waspada !")
                    .setPositiveButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }).show();
        }
        else if ( dB >= 100) {
            AlertDialog.Builder build = new
                    AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            build.setTitle("Alert!!!").setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setMessage("Level 100 dB, berbahaya jika lebih dari 1 menit!!! Segera menghindar")
                    .setPositiveButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }).show();
        };

}

      public void processAudioFrame(short[] audioFrame) {
        if (!mDrawing) {
          mDrawing = true;
          double rms = 0;
          for (int i = 0; i < audioFrame.length; i++) {
            rms += audioFrame[i]*audioFrame[i];
          }
          rms = Math.sqrt(rms/audioFrame.length);
          mRmsSmoothed = mRmsSmoothed * mAlpha + (1 - mAlpha) * rms;
          final double rmsdB = 20.0 * Math.log10(mGain * mRmsSmoothed);
          dB = 20 + rmsdB;

          mBarLevel.post(new Runnable() {
              @Override
            public void run() {
              mBarLevel.setLevel(( 10 + rmsdB) / 90);
              DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##");
              mdBTextView.setText(df.format(dB));
              Alert();
              int one_decimal = (int) (Math.round(Math.abs(rmsdB * 10))) % 10;
              mdBFractionTextView.setText(Integer.toString(one_decimal));
              mDrawing = false;
        }
              });

        } else {
          mDrawingCollided++;
          Log.v(TAG, "Level bar update collision, i.e. update took longer " +
              "than 20ms. Collision count" + Double.toString(mDrawingCollided));
        }
      }  
    }
```

Comment: You have not explained your problem well.. what exactly you want to achieve and where are you stucking with your code.

Comment: yes VishalKumar is right. @Ginawan , your question was not too much clear, anyway you have to change     if (dB >= 70 || dB <80)  to  if (dB >= 70  && dB <80)   and   else if (dB >=80 || dB <100)  to  else if (dB >=80 && dB <100)

Comment: iam so sorry @Vishal and @ JeCuRo iam newbie.. ok i will explained my problem.. i was confused where to put this code to right places.. i have tried put on method onClick but failed, put to method run but also failed.. get what i meant??

Comment: @Ginawan I have edited my reply , I have copied and paste your code with the new code lines added

Comment: many thanks JeCuRo.. i put your code to method Run (); like this

mBarLevel.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
        public void run() {
          mBarLevel.setLevel(( 10 + rmsdB) / 90);
          DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##");
          mdBTextView.setText(df.format(dB));
          Alert();
          int one_decimal = (int) (Math.round(Math.abs(rmsdB * 10))) % 10;
          mdBFractionTextView.setText(Integer.toString(one_decimal));
          mDrawing = false;
    }
          });


that void Alert();

Comment: but after that i have new problem again.. when the app detect noise >= 70 dB the alert dialog show up and overlapping alert dialog before.. how to make the dialog just show up or i should put a interval? How to make intevarl?? Thanjks

Comment: @Ginawan ok , added the new code , the dialog will close after tap on Close.  Good luck

Comment: @Ginawan  Sorry, I dont know what you mean

Comment: i mean how to make interval when i tap on close the app.. when i used the code at my comment before there will be overlapping alert dialog..

Comment: @Gimawan , I updated the code I posted , so you can copy and paste it again and the overlapping shoulb be fixed

Comment: @JeCuRo, you add int dB in void Alert() right? But red cross show up when i copy the code in void Alert on void Run.. how?